# Algebraic over a Field

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know that if $a$ is algebraic over $F$, then $[F(a):F]=n$. But is it true that if $[F(a): F]=n$, then $a$ is algebraic over $F$?

Comment: This is meaningless until you tell us what "$n$" is...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** If $[F(a):F]=n$ show that $1,a,a^2,.., a^n$ are linearly dependent over $F$. What does this mean?

Comment: Thank you very much. I get what you mean. So brilliant !

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because the family $\{1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\ldots, \alpha^n\}$ is of cardinal $n+1\geqslant \mathrm{dim}F(\alpha)$, so they don't form a free family : you have coefficients so that $\sum_{k=0}^n \lambda_i \alpha^i = 0$, and the polynomial $P(X) = \sum_{k=0}^n \lambda_i X^i$ is null on $\alpha$.